# ¿Qué probabilidades hay de que un `Guid` se repita?

Tags: c#, .net

Yo suelo utilizar mucho los [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) pero nunca me pregunte como funcionan o si existe una posibilidad de que se repitan.

Alguien puede darme una explicación del por que los [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) son tan seguros para utilizarle como identificador único en mis sistemas, o en que caso es bueno o no utilizar [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: esto lo puede ayudar pero esta en ingles -> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823/

Comment: Andres, en que tipo de sistemas? windows mobile o aplicaciones desktop? en que caso es bueno, yo opino que depende  lo que requieras en tu sistema. Hoy en día puedes generar un guid de 64 bits por ejemplo pero aún así exista la posibilidad aunque muy remota de tener una colision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Las probabilidades de colisión de un GUID de 128 bits, son **astronómicamente bajas**.

Teniendo la suficiente entropía y considerando que el generador aleatorio sea lo suficientemente bueno... si generas 2.6 x 10<sup>18</sup> guids, (o 2,600,000,000,000,000,000), la probabilidad de colisión es de un 1% ([birthday attack en la wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_cumplea%C3%B1os)).

Eso quiere decir que por cada trillón de Guids que generas, es más dificil que dos Guids colisionen, que que el ordenador se fría porque le caiga un rayo.. *varias veces!*

Dicho todo esto, la idea de que la memoria RAM de un ordenador implemente ECC (*el código de corrección de errores*), aunque tiene otras ventajas añadidas, viene de unos estudios que hizo IBM en los 90 donde indicaban que los rayos cósmicos causaban problemas (*bit-flipping*) en la memoria, y que el bit de paridad no siempre era suficiente, así que las posibilidades astronómicas no hay que tomárselas a la ligera...

Si usas Guid, yo comprobaría colisiones... siendo algo tan raro, el código de comprobación debería ser eficiente, y no te estás jugando ser el tipo con más suerte del mundo.

Sobre si usar Guid o no, eso es muy de opinión:

a mí particularmente no me gusta para sistemas donde sólo hay un generador de IDs. Los Guids son especialmente buenos en sistemas distribuidos, donde se pueden estar generando IDs en varios sitios diferentes que no están conectados entre sí (pero que se conectan en algún momento)... yo para el resto de casos, uso IDs numéricos secuenciales, o como mucho HI-LO si el rendimiento es crítico.

Comment: Otra manera de verlo es: Si se genera un GUID por microsegundo contínuamente. Demoraríamos más de 82.000 años en conseguir ese 1% de chances de repetir uno.